# How do I access the variables of the method argument?

Tags: java, methods, this

[Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw93z.png)

There are instance variables for the numerator and denominator but I don't know if using "this" would get the argument's variables or the variables for the Fraction that the method is used on. How would I get both of their variables? There's no get method btw.

Comment: Please put the code as *text* in your question, rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

"this" keyword is used for the object that contains the method, so you would use this.variable if you are referring to something outside of the method, and would not use it when referring to the parameters passed to the method. A better explanation of the "this" keyword in Java can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_this.asp

Answer (score 0):

If your *public variable* and *method argument* have same name use `this`

*public variable* - `this.yourVariable`

*method argument*        -`yourVariable`